On requirements for the method begin() of a single-pass range
According cppreference (std::ranges::range):

Semantic requirements
Given an expression E such that decltype((E)) is T, T models range only if

...
both ranges::begin(E) and ranges::end(E) are amortized constant time and do not alter the value of E in a manner observable to equality-preserving expressions, and


But is it reasonable to require that for a single-pass range the function ranges::begin(E) is amortized constant time? Indeed, for such a range, the method E.begin() will actually contain a call of something like E.get_next_value(). Accordingly, if E is not a collection of predefined elements (for example if E is a stream or E is like a stream), then the above requirement cannot be satisfied.

I fail to see how your example is not constant time. Since it doesn't depend on the size of the size of the collection, it's O(1). What am I missing or missunderstand?

or are you maybe confusing complexity with actual clock time?

These are the actual calls to get the first an last element in a range.  And basically state that they should not be costly operations. So for a forward only list determining the last element would involving going over all elements (and thus you would basically do a double pass over the collection).  And for collections like this the requirement cannot be met (and you cannot use them as input for a range)

Do you really have to iterate through the list to get end(E)? Or can it return and "end-marker" instead (in O(1) time) with some clever logic for comparison?

I don't grasp your point about get_next_value. Could it be you are confusing an iterator with the value it fetches?

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think the idea is that it's a view and get_next_value() is used to get the first valid value for the view. And the obvious solution is to cache that result (as the standard specifies in a number of cases) - giving amortized constant time for some definition of amortized.

@HansOlsson - Not sure that it's the obvious solution, since we can also hang on to the view reference and thus avoid doing the single pass before it's requested. There might be some example I'm missing, but I don't know if that's what the OP means or not.

@HansOlsson -  I indicated the case when we are dealing, for example, with a stream. We won't be able to use the cache here.
(Now I found out that there is an example in the standard library itself - this is std::views::istream. its method begin()  is equivalent to *stream_ >> value_ ; return iterator {*this};)


But is it reasonable to require that for a single-pass range the function ranges::begin(E) is amortized constant time?

Yes. Constant time does not mean "blazingly fast". It means "not varying based on the length of the range". Doing a set amount of work to get the first element is constant time.
Amortised constant time means that over a large number of calls, the total work done does not depend on the length of the range, just the number of calls.
An example of this is std::filter_view::begin, which (when the underlying range models std::forward_range) finds the first element satisfying the predicate once, and stores that for subsequent calls to begin. This is linear on the first call, and constant on all further calls. Over a linear number of calls to begin, the initial linear cost is amortised to constant.

And what about this example from standard library:
std::ranges::basic_istream_view::begin
constexpr auto begin();  (since C++20)
Equivalent to *stream_ >> value_ ; return iterator {*this};.
What if value_ type is std::string, and value_ is a very large string?

@Pavel. That's still constant time w.r.t the number of strings in the stream

Understood! Thank you very much!

If amortized constant time was only "constant time" w.r.t. the length of the range itself, it wouldn't make sense that ranges::filter_view would have to do something special to fulfil the requirement (making it "amortized constant time" w.r.t. the size of the original range). To me it seems that both "amortized" and "constant time" are underspecified in the C++23 standard for ranges.

@HansOlsson filter_view has to advance the underlying range to get to the first element, but it may only do that once.

@Caleth - Agreed, so what requirement would it break if it advanced it multiple times (for a forward-range)?

@HansOlsson it would break [range.range-2.2]. Strictly speaking, it doesn't make sense to talk about amortized constant begin for a single pass range.

@Caleth - Exactly, but that is in term of the number of elements of the underlying range, not in terms of the elements of the range we are looking at. Even though natural I cannot see that it is defined anywhere.

If you look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view you see how the standard itself handles it.
For a ranges::forward_range the result of the begin-call is cached, giving amortized constant time if begin is called multiple times.
For a single-pass range (i.e., not ranges::forward_range) this caching is skipped. In this case begin can only be called once - I assume the idea is that amortized constant time doesn't make sense if you cannot amortize it over multiple calls.
